# Spring authentication principal lazy fetching problem

Tags: java, spring, model

I am using @AuthenticationPrincipal annotation in controller level as such

```
@PutMapping(value = "add-book", consumes = "application/json")
public GenericResponse addBook(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, @RequestBody Book book) {
    return userService.addBook(user, book);
}
```

and I am sending the user to service layer. But as seen in the user model below, there is a lazy fetched attribute called bookList.

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt", "roles", "enabled",
    "authorities", "credentialsNonExpired", "accountNonLocked", "accountNonExpired"})
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class User extends Base implements UserDetails, Serializable {

@Column(unique = true)
@Size(min = 4, max = 20)
@NotNull
private String username;

@NotNull
private String password;

@Column(unique = true)
@NotNull
@Email
private String email;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return roles.stream().map(r -> new 
SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

So in this case user provided by @AuthenticationPrincipal annotation does not containt books attribute as it is lazy fetched. So, I had to do the following in the service.

```
public GenericResponse addBook(User user, Book book) {
    User userFetched = loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());
    List<Book> bookList = userFetched.getBookList();
    bookList.add(book);
    if (userRepository.save(userFetched) != null) {
        return genericResponseService.createResponseNoError(userFetched);
    } else throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Eventhough I have user, I am using loadByUsername to avoid lazy initialization exception. Is it a good practice or can I have a better way getting bookList of user?

Comment: Could you go from another side? Set User to Book? In the Book add `ManyToOne` User reference and just save the Book via bookRepository.

Comment: users have book, books do not have owners in my case. That could be a possible solution but not the optimal one for the scenario.

Comment: The principal is detached so anyway you need to refetch the User. You can define entity graph (see https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph) for the user to eagerly fetch child books.